# i do not want to run VBA code for cells already filled with data

Tags: excel, vba

I have Googled and written a VBA code for Auto Username,Date,Time
and it works fine in my shared excel.

Once a data entered in a cell it automatically giving Username,Date,Time
after some time,when some one want to copy the data and press TAB key then
Username,Date,Time are all changing according to that person and time,date,

I just want to run vba code for just empty cells not for already data filled cells,
i mean once to get Auto Username,Date,Time thats it for the cell and i dont want it modified 2nd time even there is some action
and vba code should run for only empty cells not for data already having cells

### my vba code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If (ThisRow = 6) Then Exit Sub
        Range("I" & ThisRow).Value = Time()
        Range("A" & ThisRow).Value = Date
        Range("Z" & ThisRow).Value = Environ("username")

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will only run if column A of Target's row is empty.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If (ThisRow = 6) Then Exit Sub
        If Len(Target.Offset(, -4)) = 0 Then
            Range("I" & ThisRow).Value = Time()
            Range("A" & ThisRow).Value = Date
            Range("Z" & ThisRow).Value = Environ("username")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `LenB(Target.Offset(, -4).Value) = 0`

Comment: SJR supper, Appreciate